# How to make EditText erase evertime a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-widget

Okay i have a edit text box that takes user input. Every time the user clicks the button i would like for the text that the user typed to be gone. As of now everytime the button is clicked the text remains in the edittext. I would like the text to be erased by default without having to create a instance of EditText everytime

Thanks guys if you can help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `setText()`:

```
mEditText.setText("");
```

Comment: @Deitools I figured that, But the problem is its like 10 other on click listeners... So everytime i would have to implement this? Or could i possibly make a method that will take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

after your setContentView:

```
final EditText yourEditText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourIDEditText);
    yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
           {
               yourEditText.setText("");
           }

 });
```

With this, every time the user clicks all content is cleaned.